# How do I stop and repeat a function?

Tags: python, function, python-3.x, range

How do I stop the program if value is > 10 or < 0 and display Error and then display the question again?

```
import random

while True:

    value = int(input("Enter the amount of questions would you like to answer: "))   
    if value == (1,10):
        for i in range(value):
            numb1 = random.randint(0, 12)
            numb2 = random.randint(0, 12)
            answer = numb1 * numb2

            problem = input("What is " + str(numb1) + " * " + str(numb2) + "? ")

            if int(problem) == answer:
                print("You are Correct! Great Job!")
            elif int(problem) > answer:
                print("Incorrect, Your answer is too high!")
            elif int(problem) < answer:
                print("Incorrect, your answer is too low!")
    else:
        print(" Error, Please tpye a number 1-10 ")
```

Comment: `value` is not going to be equal to the tuple `(1, 10)`. Did you mean `1 <= value < 10`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use `if 0 < value < 10:` instead of (1,10), you can stop the loop by calling `break`.

```
import random

while True:
    value = int(input("Enter the amount of questions would you like to answer: "))
    if 0 < value < 10:
        for i in range(value):
            numb1 = random.randint(0, 12)
            numb2 = random.randint(0, 12)
            answer = numb1 * numb2

            problem = input("What is {0} * {1}? ".format(numb1, numb2))

            if int(problem) == answer:
                print("You are Correct! Great Job!")
            elif int(problem) > answer:
                print("Incorrect, Your answer is too high!")
            elif int(problem) < answer:
                print("Incorrect, your answer is too low!")
        break

    print("Error, please type a number from 1 to 10: ")
```

Comment: This would just `break` out of the first iteration of the `for` loop. Why keep the loop if you're looking for this?

Comment: @SukritKalra actually `break` is to break the `while` loop.

Comment: It was indented differently in the first answer.